# Sum of char and int leads to weird char in my c++ code

Tags: c++, char, addition

I tried searching for a solution online but I could not find one. The closet I came is  this [A similar unanswered question on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/56331/)

Here is my code....

```
int main()
{
char a[1000000],s[100000];
scanf("%s",s);
int i,l=strlen(s);


    //cout<<l;
for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    a[i]=s[l-i-1];    //to reverse the word in s[]

    cout<<a<<endl;
for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        s[i]+=a[i]-96;
        if(s[i]>'z')
        {

            int diff=s[i]-'z';
            s[i]='a'+(diff-1);

        }
    }    
   cout<<s;

return 0;
}

//l=length of string.
//a[i]=is another string with word in s[] being reversed.
```

My problem is that when I execute this and give an input , say, `world` it prints some **weird characters**.
I am unable to see any fault in the logic I applied and I feel frustrated now.

The question asked was that I am supposed to add two strings one of which is reversed version of the other one and that the addition is to be performed in such a way that `'a' + 'b' = 'c'` , `'d' + 'a' = 'e'` .... and `'z' + 'a' = 'a'`. So that the addition is closed under **small-alphabets**.

Comment: It's naughty to assume a particular *encoding* in C++ as then your code is not portable. Suggest you re-engineer, and hope the bug goes away?

Comment: You might want to look up the ASCII numbers of characters

Comment: What do you mean by particular encoding and not portable code. Would you please explain a little more?

Comment: sample input and output ...

Comment: In short, the lower case letters don't *necessarily* have to be in a consecutive block. That's why the C++ standard library has nice functions like islower, isupper, &c.

Comment: Throw it all away and start over. Use `std::string` this time. Don't use `scanf`. Also: (0) you don't null-terminate your strings; (1) an array of 1000000 characters may or may not overflow your stack; (2) 96 is not a number you want to see in your code because **no one** knows what it possibly could mean. Your addition logic is not clear. Is `z` a zero element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a signed char (a signed byte). When the signed char goes over 127, then it flips negative. This causes your computation to miss the fact that the value is out of range, and when it's printed it's converted back to a high character.

You can simply replace your wrap around check with this:

```
    while ((unsigned char)s[i] > 'z')
    {
        s[i] -= 26;
    }
```

And then your program at least does what you wanted it to do. There are good suggestions in the comments for making it more robust as well.

Comment: You assume there are 26 letters in the alphabet between A and Z, what if this will change one day? Also, `char x = 'z' + 'z'` is UB if `char` is signed 8 bit and `z` code is 122, better use `int` for intermediate calculations.

Comment: Even if ASCII 'z' somehow changes value we can assume that it's still going to be < 128, and there's going to be a contiguous block of codes for the Latin Alphabet, so the code above works for any 'z' value (127 + 127 < 256 so it doesn't wrap around), as long as our alphabet continues to have 26 letters. Which means basically forever.

Comment: @JasonLang "there's going to be a contiguous block of codes for the Latin Alphabet" not really guaranteed by anything but suppose it's true. You assume there are 26 characters in the block. Who said it will be the case in the future?

Comment: @JasonLang 8 bit signed is normally -128 to 127. Signed overflow is **undefined behaviour**. You cannot assume it's arithmetic modulo 256 or any other thing.